# How to call a Form in C# with its address?

Tags: c#, forms

In this simple code I wish to know how I can call the form with its actual address (not `this.Hide()`), so that I may close/hide it even if the form is currently not active. My main purpose is to hide `Form2` to open `Form1` on a button click, and then close `Form2` forever.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2.Hide(); // This doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: So who holds the reference to `Form2`?

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng Thanks a lot ! Your solution gave me a way to work around what I was trying to do !

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a reference since you are in the form itself already. `this`, which points to the current instance of the class in context, will do:

```
this.Hide();
```

Or, since it knows the context:

```
Hide();
```

Comment: This is the best answer, not sure why everyone else is over complicating things.

Comment: I hide form2 to open form1 then I need form2 to get closed and not the active one so I cant use this to close it.

Comment: Your code shows to hide `Form2` from `Form2`. This does that. There is no context of 'active one' or something like that. Just the current.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Because the OP doesn't want to close the current form. `this` might be part of the solution, but it isn't *the* solution. Of course, the question isn't very easy to answer with what's given as context...

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't keep form references for you, unlike Visual Basic. You need to keep them yourself. `Form2` is just the type - it has no "default reference". The main idea isn't "one instance per form type, hidden and shown as necessary" - it's "forms are objects like any other - create and dispose of them the same way as with any other objects". The usual workflow isn't `Form1.Hide(); Form2.Show();` - it's more like `Application.Run(new MainForm()); ... using (var form = new Form1()) { form.ShowDialog(); }`. That doesn't mean the VB approach cannot be used in C# - it just means you have to implement it yourself (or switch to VB.NET). If it makes sense - the design has been somewhat deprecated for a while now, so make sure you have a good idea of why you're doing things that way, rather than just inertia.

It sounds like your real problem is that you're trying to implement some kind of a wizard, or a flow through multiple forms. This means you should either use a wizard, or change the way your whole application is built.

Look into your `program.cs`. Understand what it does. When the form passed to `Application.Run` is closed, the whole application is closed. There are many ways of rewriting this, but we can't really help you in a general way - all I can tell you is that if your application doesn't fit the "main window + other windows" model, the default application setup isn't going to work for you.

Someone should be responsible for the lifetimes of both of your forms. We can't really tell you who - maybe the `Program` class, maybe one of the forms, maybe the main form that opens the two forms in a series as modal dialogs. We simply can't tell - that's a design problem for you to solve. But the one who's responsible will also handle closing and opening the individual forms at the right points in time.

Comment: How/where can I give it a reference myself?

Comment: @Zenektric -- "How" <--- by using the form's constructor to create a new instance.  "where" <-- anywhere you want.

Comment: @Zenektric At some point in your code, you do something like `new Form2()` - that creates the reference. Store it somewhere, and use that reference later. Or reconsider your design - the VB style is more or less deprecated nowadays. Are you sure it fits your use case well, or are you just using it out of inertia?

Comment: Not true. Application.OpenForms

Comment: @Steve That's something entirely different. The OP is talking about default instances, which aren't available in C#. Just because there is *a* reference doesn't mean it's the same thing. Mind you, it might actually be a good solution to the OP's *actual* problem, but I'm just pointing out that his idea of how forms work doesn't apply to C#.

Comment: When I do 'Form form2 = new Form2();' within Form2() It calls it infinite loop

Comment: Then don't call that there @Zenektric

Comment: @Zenektric Of course - `Form2()` is the constructor. You're looking at the wrong place, and likely at the wrong time. Forms are just objects like any other - treat them as such. I didn't say you're supposed to call `new Form2()` inside of the `Form2` constructor, I told you to go *look* for where you call `new Form2()`.

Comment: @Zenektric maybe you should tell what you want to accomplish....Hiding a form in the constructor is kind of pointless.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, from what the OP described, it sounds like they want to access an open `Form2` from *another* form. So "use `this`" doesn't quite cover the problem (except that you could use it to store a reference in a static field or something, of course).

Comment: I want to hide form2 to open form1 then I need form2 to get closed and not the active one so I cant use this to close it. I've coded my whole thing in Form2.cs and I wish to procede to Form1.cs for the next phase @PeterBons

Comment: @Zenektric and when do you want to open form1 in form2? after a button click or? Because the way you ask it now it will never show form2. Please update your question with this additional information.

Comment: I've not written the whole code because it has a lot of stuff unrelated to the question. I do stuff in Form2.cs and when its all done I wish to switch forms to Form1.cs for this I use the hide mechanic but I need to close the Form2 (not active) so that it doesnt keep running in background forever.

Comment: @Zenektric So Form2 is some kind of a splashscreen or a progress indicator or what? Are you doing actual work in the constructor, and attempting to hide the form while still there?

Comment: @Luaan Form2 is like half the form. It has a lot of entries and dynamically made textboxes which I input in a word doc. I submit everything then I need to collect more so I made a Form1 as a continuation to it.

Comment: @Zenektric Well, that's basically the wizard approach. You can find plenty of examples on how to implement that on the internet - or just use a sequence of modal dialogs launched from the main form (or `Program.cs` if you don't have a main form).

Comment: jdweng had a solution which gave me a better understanding on how two forms are managed with each other ! Hide the first and then while closing the second form I could select the first form to close with it. Thanks a lot everyone !

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the actual 'address' inside the instance of `Form2`. So, the hide it in the form itself do this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Hide(); // or this.Hide()
    }
}
```

If you want to hide it from somewhere else you need to call it using the reference. Like:

```
var f = new Form2();
f.Show();
// Do stuff with form
f.Hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work in `Form2` just use `this`.

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

You can also use:

```
public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Hide();
        }
```

You dont need to call something like `Form2 form = new Form2();` only if you work in another form for example like this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show(); //or form.Hide();

        }
```